# Remove show password icon in Android N

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords

New Android version automatically draws show password icon when I set `android:inputType="textPassword"` in EditText view. How can I disable it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Haven't tested it myself, my first guess would be to try: `editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: It doesn't help, still visible

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The password icon (or eye-icon) use be removed with the method [`setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(boolean)) or with [`app:passwordToggleEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:passwordToggleEnabled) through XML.

For more information see [support library revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/new_password_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_password"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Whats `no.ruter.mobile.view.EditText`?

Comment: did they remove it again in 25.0.1? Edit: Turns out they did https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: @Cremos how to control programmatically password icon 
 'app:passwordToggleEnabled'

Comment: This is deprecated. If you want to add the toggle, use: app:endIconMode="password_toggle" and to remove it: app:endIconMode="none". Can also be set in Java/Kotlin: endIconMode = END_ICON_NONE or endIconMode = END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE

Answer (score 0):

**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'**

**compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'**

in layout

```
        android:inputType="textPassword"
```

**Its Working**

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorhint"
    android:textColor="@color/colortext">
```

true means you can show/hide password