# How to use both PasswordToggle and ErrorDrawable on the EditText?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

Support library v24 added a password toggle button on TextInputLayout that shows a toggle button to reveal password for EditText with type="password":

[image]

That's great, however, I also want to use a validation error indicator if the password is not provided. But when I set the error I get this:

[image]

They are drawn on top of each other. How can I use both the password toggle and the validation error?

Comment: You should be setting the error on the `TextInputLayout`, not the `EditText`.

Comment: That works but I much prefer the error indicator style, that doesn't shift the layout and insert text. But it does seem the only way, if you post as answer I can accept it.

Comment: Yeah, `TextInputLayout` was written to follow Google's own prescribed design, so they don't offer a lot in the way of customization on that, other than like text size, color, and whatnot. If you don't mind, I'll just mark this a duplicate, as it's been asked before. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate. thanks

Comment: As soon as I did that, I realized that might've been jumping the gun. I've written several different custom `TextInputLayout` classes; this should be doable. Lemme do some tests later when I get a chance, and I'll see if we can accomplish what you want here without a huge overhaul to the class.

Comment: Well, that would be awesome. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I just got a chance to start digging into this, and it seems there might be a pretty simple way to handle this. It looks like you can just use the `TextInputLayout#setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled()` method to show/hide that eye icon as needed; e.g., in a `TextWatcher`. I've not run any tests yet, as I don't have any recent support library versions on my machine atm, but its functionality is covered in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39019675). Also, it looks like it's off by default in 25.0.1: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html.