# Change to custom icon from eye-icon(default) for hide-show password in android EditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to change/display different icons for show password in android edittext.
I am using following code to display icon.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTextInput"
    android:textColorHint="@color/aluminium">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextValue"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to use custom icons instead of normal icons(eye-icon). Please help me.

Comment: Did you try checking [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:passwordToggleDrawable)?

Comment: I don't think that your code will show `normal icons(eye-icon)`

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019675/remove-show-password-icon-in-android-n

Comment: you can check this link http://codevscolor.com/2016/08/android-material-design-tutorial-10-password-visibility-toggle/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Create a new drawable file and named it as **show_password_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_18dp" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off_black_18dp"/>
</selector>
```

and in your layout file, add `app:passwordToggleDrawable` attribute in `TextInputLayout` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTextInput"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/show_password_selector"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextValue"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

For Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW0YIV0Z9qk

Answer (score 9):

Use `app:passwordToggleDrawable` to change the icon.
Use `app:passwordToggleTint` to change the color of the icon, this will only work if the icon is a vector drawable.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTextInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_on">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to use default eye icon (show/hide password) but change the icon color
then you simply put the line

```
app:passwordToggleTint="@color/yourColor"
```

If you would like to use custom eye icon, you should use

```
app:passwordToggleDrawable
```

to change the icon. and use

```
app:passwordToggleTint
```

to change the color of the icon. your custom icon color does not show. Tint color will be shown. The whole xml code like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabelLogin"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/yourColor"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/show_password_selector">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_line_shape"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/yourColor"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and show_password_selector.xml is given below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hide_password" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_show_password" /></selector>
```

Hope that will help all.

Answer (score 4):

**app:passwordToggleEnabled** in **TextInputLayout** Property

**Add Dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Example changing the icon of show/hide password (`ic_baseline_add_24` <=> hide password, `ic_baseline_edit_24` <=> show password)

**drawable/ic_showhide_password.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"/>
</selector>
```

**xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_showhide_password"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This helped me achieve my goal. I wanted to use custom eye and eye with slash icons. Same behavior as the default for password_toggle but different icons. This works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Note: I know OP asked for custom icons but in case you just need a password toggle then `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` already provides default icons.

Answer (score 2):

In your Xml Make a RelativeLayout with `TextInputLayout` and `Imageview`

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTextInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColorHint="#3f3f3f">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordedit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/bluelocked"
                    android:drawablePadding="13dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
                    android:textColorHint="#3f3f3f"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagepassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/IMAGEYOUWANT" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And in your Activity add `onTouch()` method for showing and hidding your password.

```
    ImageView imagepass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagepassword);
    imagepass .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    editpass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    editpass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Material Components library just use the the **`app:endIconDrawable`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/...."
    ..>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      ../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I implement it using text.. that is 'Show' and 'Hide'

```
textViewShowPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (textViewShowPassword.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Show")) {
                editTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                textViewShowPassword.setText("Hide");
                editTextPassword.setSelection(editTextPassword.getText().length());
            } else {
                textViewShowPassword.setText("Show");
                editTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
                editTextPassword.setSelection(editTextPassword.getText().length());
            }

        }
    });
```

Hope this help for you..!!

Answer (score 0):

1.create a xml layout...I have created in my way

```
                   <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etCurrentPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/drawable_edit_text_2"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:hint="@string/old_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_10dp" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgShowPassword1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_12dp"
                        android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_eye" />
                </FrameLayout>
```

2.In activity class: call the method with the mathing parameters

```
showORhidePass(view,etRetypePassword,showPassword3 = !showPassword3);

void showORhidePass(AppCompatImageView imageView, AppCompatEditText editText, Boolean save){

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())){
            return;
        }

        if (save){
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            editText.setSelection(editText.length());
            imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.darker_gray));
        }else{
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            editText.setSelection(editText.length());
            imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android Material library all you need is -> `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_password"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password_EditText"
        style="@style/EditText_Common_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:errorEnabled="true" />
        
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```