# TextInputLayout passwordToggle icon set enabled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Is there any way to do `setEnabled = false`  passwordToggle icon?

I change the color of passwordToggle icon when there is no text in password field. (I make it look disabled-not clickable) but of course it still works.

`textinputlayout.setEnabled = false` makes all layout untouchable so that doesn't work.

[image: Sample image (not mine)]

Idea : I can customize the toggle button, I can use same disabled icon for both clicked and unclicked, that is just a workaround and its hard to find default icon. 
[Change to custom icon from eye-icon(default) for hide-show password in android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173249/change-to-custom-icon-from-eye-icondefault-for-hide-show-password-in-android-e)