# How to place an ImageView beside EditText password input field

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to do password visibility toggle in password field using EditText TextView (I dont want to use the android support TextInputLayout)

Everything working but how do I pace the ImageView In the right position beside the password EditText field.

This is what I have now

[image: Password visibility]

This is what I want

[image: Password]

I want the image to be at that position inside the password EditText field.

My layout file

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_border"
    android:hint="Your Password" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/show_pass_btn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:onClick="ShowHidePass"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/eye_show" />
```

Comment: `I dont want to use the android support TextInputLayout)` why?. its easy.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya looks so different from the normal editText field which I prefer.

Comment: I have done the java code just looking for a way to place that image beside the editText field

Comment: @Ibramazin What you are looking for is exactly a TextInputLayout. Just use the right style

Comment: TextInputLayout have that functionality https://stackoverflow.com/a/44173975/4017501

Comment: Is there a way of making textInputLayout to look like the normal editText without the material input field and floating label just normal editText? @cutiko

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest two solutions. I am using the second one myself

### First: By adding a drawable to an EditText

You can add an icon to the EditText like this:

```
    <EditText
        ...
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_settings_24dp"
        ...
    />
```

and then add a listener to it like this: [Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

### Second: By extending TextInputLayout

I was having the same issue so what i did was to create a view class that extends TextInputLayout. That way the material theme does not apply the filled box style by default and you still get all the TextInputLayout goodness.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

```
    <com.passwordstore.android.ui.views.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_notes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/notes"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_generate_password"
        style="@style/BoxTextInputLayout">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium" />
    </com.passwordstore.android.ui.views.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

**And here's the result**

[Old EditText design with TextInputLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZf3X.png)

Comment: Not sure why you try to reinvent the wheel - TextInputLayout does that out of the box

Comment: Yeah i am still using TextInputLayout however it applies a default FilledBox style to the EditText. I don't know any way to disable that style so i wrapped the TextInputLayout in a custom class. That way the AppTheme doesn't add the material style to it.

Comment: No reason to extend the TextInputLayout in this way. Just change the style

Comment: Tried all the available styles for TextInputLayout, None seems to work though. Do you have any idea which style gives back the old EditText design ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` in `TextInputLayout` and, if you also need to give custom icon use, `"app:passwordToggleDrawable="`

```
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
        
                            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/ed_password"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"  
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="Password"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:padding="10dp" />
        
        
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorOrange"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginUsername" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/password_toggle_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/loginPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/loginPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/loginPassword"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_visibility_24"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.